# Firebase security rules throwing error for Firestore .where() snapshot

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Getting error:

> Uncaught Error in onSnapshot: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Here is the function that is being called:

```
let unsubscribeUserThings
export function getUserThings(user, state) {
    unsubscribeUserThings = firebaseDB.collection("things").where("user", "==", user)
        .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
            var things = {}
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                things[doc.id] = doc.data()
            })

            state.setState({
                things: things
            })
        })

}
export function stopListeningToUserThings() {
    // Stop listening to changes
    unsubscribeUserThings()
}
```

The Firebase security rules are:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // FUNCTIONS

      // True if the signed in user is the thing's user
      function isThingUser() {
        return request.auth != null && request.auth.uid != null && resource.data.user == request.auth.uid
      }

      // True if the signed in user is the thing's owner
      function isThingOwner() {
        return request.auth != null && request.auth.uid != null && resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid
      }

    // RULES

      // Things
      match /things/{thingID} {
        allow create: if true
        allow read, update: if isThingUser() || isThingOwner()
      }
  }
}
```

What's strange is that it's still showing everything correctly, just firing this error. Why is this happening? Do I ignore it?

Comment: A query cannot simultaneously give results and also generate a permission error.  It has to be either one or the other.  The only situation I can think of that would yield both results and an error is when something changes in the data *after* the first set of results is given, but *before* the listener is unsubscribed, that changes the validity of the original query.

Comment: Thank you, @DougStevenson-- your answer pointed me in the right direction! See my solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All was fine and good with the Firebase rules-- it ended up being pulled by a different onSnapshot call to listen to a subcollection of the "thing" documents, subcollection "parts." Added a nested match statement to give it permission to read /things/{thingID}/parts/{partID} and all is working now!

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // FUNCTIONS

      // True if the signed in user is the thing's user
      function isThingUser() {
        return request.auth != null && request.auth.uid != null && resource.data.user == request.auth.uid
      }

      // True if the signed in user is the thing's owner
      function isThingOwner() {
        return request.auth != null && request.auth.uid != null && resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid
      }

  // RULES

    // Things
    match /things/{thingID} {
      allow create: if true
      allow read, update: if isThingUser() || isThingOwner()

      match /parts/{partID} {
        allow read, write: if true
      }
    }
  }
}
```